# toSet.SetValue only taking first option in array

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm using itext7 .net to modify and fill an existing pdf. I have a problem with populating combo boxes with the right value.

In the below code sample, I'm creating a list of options to fill Combo Box7, and then set the value to "8.30 am - 12.30 pm". when I open/print/download the pdf, the value of that combo box always comes as "Any", which is the first option in the list.

```
IList<PdfObject> options = new List<PdfObject>();
options.Add(new PdfString("Any"));
options.Add(new PdfString("8.30 am - 12.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("12.30 pm - 4.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("4.30 pm - 8.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("8.30 pm - 12.30 am"));
options.Add(new PdfString("12.30 am - 4.30 am"));
options.Add(new PdfString("4.30 am - 8.30 am"));
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray(options);
fields["Combo Box7"].SetOptions(arr);
fields["Combo Box7"].SetValue("8.30 am - 12.30 pm");
//OR
//fields.TryGetValue("Combo Box7", out toSet);
//toSet.SetOptions(arr);
//toSet.SetValue("8.30 am - 12.30 pm");
```

I expect the option in the combo box to be set to "8.30 am - 12.30 pm", but it's showing "Any" or any value I put as the first option in the list.

Comment: I would actually recommend using SelectedIndex in this case.

Comment: Just a rough idea: what if you use [SetIndices](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.0.7/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfChoiceFormField.html#setIndices-com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfArray-) or [SetListSelected](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.0.7/com/itextpdf/forms/fields/PdfChoiceFormField.html#setListSelected-java.lang.String:A-) method instead of SetValue?